# using 3D rotations in css3

Tags: css

what are the three parameters in rotation?
A lot of resources have described about the fourth parameter(ex: [enter link description here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/rotate3d/) but not much about the first three in:

```
rotate(x, y, z, adeg)
```

the fourth appears the angle in degrees for all the axes, then are the first three, some kind of a scalar factor, what is their maximum value? What do these implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform: rotate3d(x,y,z, angle)`

rotate3d rotates an object around a vector axis. That's what (x,y,z)  are for. They determine a vector around which the object will be rotated. ( the coordonates for the vector on the 3 axes )

also you should know that Y axis in 3d is inverted, meaning that it's positive values are down the axis not up as in 2d

The relation between these 3 values is important in setting the vector . for example `rotate3d(1,-1,1,60deg)` gives the same result as `rotate3d(100, -100, 100, 60deg)`  or more clear : `rotate3d(1,-5,8,60deg)` the same as `rotate3d(10,-50,80,60deg)`

```css
div {

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin:50px;
}
.first {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 60deg);
}
.second {
     transform: rotate3d(100, -100, 100, 60deg);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
<div class="first">

</div>
<div class="second">

</div>
```